# How to stop a Flask server running gevent-socketio

Tags: python, socket.io, flask

I have a flask application running with gevent-socketio that I create this way:

```
server = SocketIOServer(('localhost', 2345), app, resource='socket.io')
gevent.spawn(send_queued_messages_loop, server)
server.serve_forever()
```

I launch `send_queued_messages_loop` in a gevent thread that keeps on polling on a `gevent.Queue` where my program stores data to send it to the socket.io connected clients

I tried different approaches to stop the server (such as using `sys.exit`) either from the socket.io handler (when the client sends a socket.io message) or from a normal route (when the client makes a request to `/shutdown`) but in any case, `sys.exit` seems to fail because of the presence of greenlets.

I tried to call `gevent.shutdown()` first, but this does not seem to change anything

What would be the proper way to shutdown the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `serve_forever()` create a `gevent.event.Event` and wait for it. To actually initiate shutdown, trigger the event using its `set()` method:

```
from gevent.event import Event
stopper = Event()

server = SocketIOServer(('localhost', 2345), app, resource='socket.io')
server.start()
gevent.spawn(send_queued_messages_loop)

try:
    stopper.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print
```

No matter from where you now want to terminate your process - all you need to do is calling `stopper.set()`.

The `try..except` is not really necessary but I prefer not getting a stacktrace on a clean CTRL-C exit.